# Advanced Vue router guards

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I have my routers set up like this:

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'HomePage',
    component: HomePage,
    beforeEnter: checkAuth,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: false,
      showSidebar: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/feed',
    name: 'FeedPage',
    component: FeedPage,
    beforeEnter: checkAuth,
    beforeRouteEnter: ((to, from, next) => {
      console.log(from)
    }),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      showSidebar: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/faq',
    name: 'FAQPage',
    component: FAQPage,
    beforeEnter: checkAuth,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true,
      showSidebar: true
    }
  },
 }
]
```

So **checkAuth** is a function that basically checks wether the user is authenticated before Entering that route (using google auth), which works perfectly. But I also want to use **beforeRouteEnter** to check whether the user's designation is allowed in that route AFTER authentication. I have the designation *stored* in the Vuex store.

How can I use **this** keyword such that I can use the plugins?

And also, what is the proper way to use **beforeRouteEnter**?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Vue Router documentations, The **beforeRouteEnter** guard does **NOT** have access to **this**, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed, thus the new entering component has not even been created yet.

However, you can access the instance by passing a callback to next. The callback will be called when the navigation is confirmed, and the component instance will be passed to the callback as the argument:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
     // access to component instance via `vm`
  })
}
```

Also there are `beforeRouteUpdate` & `beforeRouteLeave` you might want use as well based on your needs, for these `this` is available ( but passing callback is not supported on these two )

Comment: Can I use this in the routers or does it have to be in the component?

Comment: These 3 are `In-Component Guards` so you can use them inside route components (the ones passed to the router configuration)

Answer (score 0):

`beforeEnter`and `beforeRouteEnter` are both guards with the same goal, the difference is where to use it.

`beforeEnter` is a guard you can define on a route's configuration object. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

`beforeRouteEnter` is a guard you define on your component.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Either way if you want to access you Vuex Store you should import it.
This could be an Example of your **FeedPage** component usign `beforeRouteEnter`

```
<script>
import Store from '../vuexstore.js'
export default{
  beforeRouteEnter(to,from,next){
    if(Store.state.isAllowed){ 
      next() 
    } else { 
      next(false) 
    }                 
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to use `next()` to continue the navigation after the validation.